# Angular component pattern communication

Tags: angularjs

After much searching I am still having trouble wrapping my head around something.

lets say I have a video player directive that needs to play able to respond to other play button directives that may or may not be siblings.
When I say respond I mean that when the play button is clicked, it could tell the video player directive to play the video.

FYI The video player is NOT the html5 video player, it is a jankaty iframe thing that needs a jankaty postmessage api to communicate. (that part I have figured out :)

```
<some-component>
video player in here somewhere
</some-component>

<play-button></play-button>
...
<play-button></play-button>
```

How can this be achieved using the component directive pattern. I'm trying to stay away in this case from controllers not bound to directives.

## Questions

Is having the video player directive listen on a $rootScope event evil ? People seem to have their opinions mixed on this.

This seems like a use case and a concept that would be fairly regular.(Components that are not siblings or children needing to communicate) Is using a intermediate service really the only clean way to do this? It seems like having a player service would be overkill just for it to provide play/pause functions and track state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be a good Idea. I'm going to do what the ngForm directive does. The ngform directive takes in a name and exposes its controller to that name object on the parent scope.

This method will work on a wrapping controller or wrapping component. 
Here is a small example.
http://plnkr.co/edit/3kvWKdckrW2cErRS9yIj?p=preview

```
<wrapping-component or ctrl>
  <player name="ctrl.player">
  </some-component>

  <play-button player="ctrl.player"></play-button>
  ...
  <play-button player="ctrl.player"></play-button>
</wrapping-component or ctrl>
```

Caveat: The player directive most likley can't be an isolate scope.

EDIT:

The player directive can be an isolate scope directive. By utilizing the $parse service you can do this.

```
var setter = $parse(ctrl.name).assign; //You could also use $scope.name, I'm using bindToController.
setter($scope.$parent, ctrl)//Sets the directive controller on the parent scope as the ctrl.name value
```

So now if you have

```
<player name="player4"></player>
```

You can now say later within this parent scope.

```
...ng-click="player4.play()"
```

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Although these components which you describe are independent, at least one (controls) cannot (or mabye should not) live without the other.

Player controls obviously belong to the player and in some way should have an over arching connection between the player and the controls. If you don't want to store data in an views or higher order controller, then instead I would recommend nesting both the players and controls in a directive/component itself, both which have access to that directives controller.

That way responsibilities, are still isolated to the overall "Parent" component.

### Answers to your questions:

*Is having the video player directive listen on a $rootScope event evil?*

**Evil, no. Still used to abuse events at a global scope for people to access from anywhere in their app? Yes. From a code maintenance standpoint, event listeners like this can become a pain because you are constantly having to ensure that both listener and emitter are updated together. Sure this may be trivial, however the less code to maintain, the better.**

*Is using a intermediate service really the only clean way to do this?*

**Besides wrapping both component in a parent component, most likely. Services when injected are available as a singleton, and are also available to be accessed from any directed as long as it is injected. So one could say that this would be appropriate. It may *seem* like overkill but it separates concerns and allows code to be modular.**

Comment: Thanks, I suppose a service would be better in my case due to the fact that the parent component shouldn't even care if it has a player inside of it or not? But then the service would need to know which player on the page(in the case of multiple players) it needs to set the playing state to. What about a $scope.watch within the player component that upon change of the playing state variable within the directive calls the js api of the player that then plays it. So many ways to do it! :(